# How can I connect to servers after upgrading to the latest version?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I just updated Minecraft and now servers will not accept me.

I get the message 'Failed to connect with minecraft.net,' I have tried this about 4 or 5 times and I have no idea how to fix it!

I wish I had not upgraded, is it possible to return to the previous version?

Would making a new account help?

Comment: Explain in more detail. The problem is you are probably using 1.9, and almost all servers use 1.8.

Comment: As far as I know though, that would cause a connection refused error instead of a failed to connect to minecraft.net

Answer (score 1):

You can select the version of minecraft you want to play using the profile editor in the minecraft launcher.

Just before loging in you can go to `Edit Profile`. A screen pops up and at the bottom of the screen you can select the version.

Just launch the game and it will install everything nicely and tou can play on servers again.